# Google Compute Engine Firewall

Tags: google-compute-engine

When I create an instance in Google Compute Engine the instance is created with a default network and firewall. Does this firewall preclude the use of activating the firewall in Ubuntu itself?

In other words, is enabling the ufw in Ubuntu redundant for an ecommerce implementation?

Thank you.

Comment: For whatever it's worth, I've had two separate occasions where I've made rules changes to firewalls in Google Compute Engine and lost unrelated connectivity between instances for a short period of time, causing a complete crash of our application stack. Both times, support insisted it was a complete coincidence and refused to acknowledge the problem. The simplified management of the GCE firewall is still worth it, but you might consider other options if you have very high network uptime requirements and few maintenance windows to make changes.

Comment: This is good to know and now I'll know to look for it when setting up load-balancing.  Thanks.  Sounds like GCE is typically complicated behind the scenes so it's easy on the user with the price being a few bugs.

Comment: I would also like to know if GCE firewall should generally be enough (without configuring a firewall on each node).. Having things not working because TWO firewalls are configured correctly can be a pain.

Comment: @AshleyAitken Having worked with Google Compute Engine, I can confidently state that for most operations and security requirements, the GCE firewall [via instance tag] is sufficient by itself.

Answer (score 3):

Wont hurt to run additional firewalls. Some may have richer features that the GCE firewall doesnt have, or might help in case the GCE firewall has a security hole.
The drawback is that its more work to configure and later maintain individual firewalls if you have several instances, and you will consume a little more resources to run the extra firewall.

Comment: Thank you. My concern is that there may be an infrastructure 'gap' between the GCE firewall and the linux kernel/disk.   At this early stage of working with servers and GCE in particular, I can't 'see' the architecture on the other end.  Is my linux disk vulnerable if the firewall is off and the GCE infrastructure is compromised on an adjacent rack/disk/network/instance?  In the end, it's obvious to take every precaution so I've enable ufw.

Comment: Sorry, but, of course it won't hurt and may have richer features... but is it, generally speaking, necessary to use two firewalls (GCE and node firewall)?

Comment: Unless its affecting your performance I dont see why not. Software is never perfect.

Answer (score 0):

It is not redundant, as long as you enabled ufw and permitted port 22. Cause most of the time once ufw has been enabled on the VM instance side. Port 22 is always forgot to exclude.

GCP firewall rules is different to UFW of VM instance.